# Are the fibers of a retraction always connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected topological space, and $Z$ be a subspace of $X$. Suppose $f:X \to Z$ is a retraction, i.e. a mapping of topological spaces such that $f \circ i = id_Z$, where $i:Z \to X$ is the inclusion.

Is it true that all fibers of $f$ are connected?

PS: By fiber, I simply mean the preimage of a point $z\in Z$.

Comment: By fiber do you mean homotopy fiber or the preimage of a point?

Comment: @pancini thank you for pointing this out, I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z\subset\Bbb R^2$ be the line segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and let $X$ be the union of $Z$ with the upper half of the unit circle. Define $f\colon X\to Z$ as projection onto $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$.

It is not true that the all fibers of $f$ are connected: $f^{-1}(x,0)$ is two disjoint points whenever $|x|<1$.

Comment: For the record, I'm pretty sure the last line is also true for homotopy fibers. I believe all homotopy fibers will have two connected components. But I'd have to remind myself how they are topologized in the first place to be sure.